# Google data studio embed only one page

Tags: embed, looker-studio

I have embedded GDS report via iframe. The report has 5 pages.

I know it is possible to set a page that should be visible after the report is loaded into the iframe.

Let's say that I want to show only the 3rd page from the report.

Is it possible to embed only one page from the report with an iframe?